# HTML value in Cookie

Tags: c#, .net

This may have been answered but I can't find what I'm looking for.

I am building a simple html table from data a user enters in a form. I need this data to be emailed to them and also displayed on another page, however, we are not saving it to the database.

To solve this issue, I decided to store the html string in a cookie and just read that cookie on the page where it is needed.

However, the value of the cookie is being truncated and I'm not sure why. Here is what I have:

```
    string str = "";

    str += "<p>Please print this form and send it with your repair.<br /><b>INSTRUMENT REPAIR FORM</b><p>";

    str += "<table style='width: 800px'>";
    str += "<tr><td>CUST #</td><td>" + txtCustomerNum.Text + "</td><td>NAME & ADDRESS</td><td>" + txtName.Text + "</td></tr>";
    str += "<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>" + txtAddress.Text + "</td></tr>";
    str += "<tr><td>PHONE</td><td>" + txtPhone.Text + "</td><td>AUTHORIZED BY</td><td>" + "________________________" + "</td></tr>";
    str += "</table>";

    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("InsRepairFormCookie");
    myCookie.Value = str;

    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

When I read the cookie, it's being truncated after the `800px;`. What do I need to do to store this entire string as the cookie value?

Comment: Have you tried it using `Session` instead? I believe the `Session` won't truncate the value. I've did a very simple search on Google and there are some problems. http://goo.gl/sao2XI. If you're sticking with the cookie I'd suggest to try encoding its content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a good idea to use StringBuilder. It saves on memory, and only creates one string where as this method is creating at least 2 for every +=. Only having the one string should resolve the issue you are facing as well, though it wouldn't be a bad idea to encode it as Esteban suggested.

```
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder;

    str.Append("<p>Please print this form and send it with your repair.<br /><b>INSTRUMENT REPAIR FORM</b><p>");

    str.Append("<table style='width: 800px'>");

...

    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("InsRepairFormCookie");
    myCookie.Value = str.ToString();

    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

Comment: where is the encoding?

Comment: myCookie.Value = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode("str.ToString");

Comment: However both Mathieson and Estibon are right, you really should use session, it would be faster client side.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer because it does actually answer the specific question asked. I am, however, refactoring this based on all the suggestions I received. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Separate your display data and actual business data.  What are the values on the form you're interested in?  Make an object with fields for them, and store that in the session.  Cookies are designed for small ids, not data like you're using.  Realize that every page load will be bringing that cookie across.

The Session stores the info on the server, and then uses the cookie to just signal which user the data should be retrieved from.